# Unable to connect to a Windows Instance using Ansible Playbook

Tags: windows, ansible, winrm

Every time I try running a playbook to automate some installations in **Windows Server**, my Windows Remote Host seems to be **unreachable**.

Here, I am trying to install IIS Server and my **playbook** looks like this :

```
---
- hosts : windows
  tasks :
- name : Install Microsoft IIS
  win_feature :
    name : Web-Server
    state : present
```

And the **error** is :

```
fatal: [ec2-54-197-197-91.compute-1.amazonaws.com]: UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false,
"msg": "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ec2-54-197-197-91.compute-1.amazonaws.com', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x1b11310>, 'Connection to ec2-54-197-197-91.compute-1.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=30)'))",
"unreachable": true
}
```

But, now I came to know that, to run playbooks for Windows, I need to have **winrm** installed on my control node.

I have done the following :

```
pip install "pywinrm>=0.1.1"
```

I have added the public ip of Windows Instance and my **hosts file** looks like:

```
[local]
127.0.0.1

[aws]
ec2-54-152-85-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[windows]
ec2-54-197-197-91.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Then, I created a directory **"group_vars"** in **/etc/ansible**, and in that a file **windows.yml** which reads :

```
ansible_user: Administrator
ansible_password: SecretPasswordGoesHere
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>(most likely, because you have not mentioned it)</sup>

You need to configure remote commands in PowerShell on your Windows instance (as described in the [Windows system prep](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#windows-system-prep) section). Execute the following (with administrator permissions):

```
iwr https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex
```

---

Before, depending on your settings, you might also need to enable the PowerShell execution policy, set the network interface to private network (mind the `InterfaceAlias` value below) and enable PowerShell remoting.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -NetworkCategory Private
Enable-PSRemoting
```

Comment: @prudhvi On the Windows machine you want to connect to. You execute PowerShell commands by typing them into PowerShell window.

Comment: When I type "Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -NetworkCategory Private" command....I get the following error :                                                                                                         Set-NetConnectionProfile : No MSFT_NetConnectionProfile objects found with property 'InterfaceAlias' equal to 'Ethernet0'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_InterfaceAlias,Set-NetConnectionProfile

Comment: Please read and try to understand my answer before running the commands.

Comment: Should'nt I use the value "Ethernet0" for InterfaceAlias?? I am totally confused what to use

Comment: I don't know what value you should use. It is your system and I have no access to it. I don't even know if you need to run it at all (if you for example set your network to "private", or disabled the firewall). I have written that clearly: first, as a side note separated from the answer related to Ansible, second; preceded by words "it depends" and with potential form "you might need".